# mongodb with mongoose; trouble updating 1 document in

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Thank you for taking a look.

Here is my code:

from models/Cart.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    owner: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    products: [ {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product', quantity:     Number} ],
    created: Date,
    updated: Date
});


exports.Cart = mongoose.model('Cart', CartSchema);
```

---

from cart.js

```
var model = require('../models/Cart');
//modify a cart
router.post('/update/:id', function(req, res, next){
  var cart = model.Cart();
  console.log(cart);
  cart.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    products: req.body.products,
    updated: moment().format()
  }, {new:true}, function(err, result){
    if(err) throw err;
    res.status(200).send(result);
  });
});
```

The error I get is `undefined is not a function` right at cart.findByIdAndUpdate and cart logs as `{ products: [], _id: 56b3b9fcd13a19a87bddd5f3 }`.

Comment: How is your '/models/Cart.js' looks like? include it's code into the question as well!

Answer (score 1):

Try by Remove or comment this line: `//var cart = model.Cart();`
and replace `cart` with `model` on line `cart.findByIdAndUpdate(......)` as well.

Comment: let me know what happens after this.

Comment: which version of mongoose you're using?

Comment: ^4.1.12 is the version

Comment: try with this as well: `model.findById(req.params.id, function (err, obj) {
 if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
 if(!obj) { throw new Error(err); }

 obj.products: req.body.products;
    obj.updated: moment().format();

 obj.save(function (err) {
   if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
   res.status(200).send(result);
 });
});`

Comment: there is another way as well see: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html

Comment: also try with `{ $set: { obj.products: req.body.products, obj.updated: moment().format() }}` in update param.